# How to connect to ieee8021x Network using connman

Tags: networking, wpa2-eap

Connect to my private WPA2 Wifi with connman works like a charm (followed [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Connman#Wi-Fi) instructions).
But when I try to connect to ieee8021x Network, i always get this error:

> Error /net/connman/service/wifi_801f024ae577_556e6974796d65646961205769666953706f74_managed_ieee8021x: Invalid arguments

I suppose something is wrong with my config file placed in /var/lib/connman :

```
[global]
Name = UnityMedia

[service_umWifiSpot]
Type = wifi
SSID = 556e6974796d65646961205769666953706f74
EAP = peap
Phase2 = MSCHAPV2
Iddentit=unitymedia/myUsername
#AnonymousIdentity=anonymous@foo.edu
Passphrase=myPassword
```

This is how i try to connect:

```
connmanctl> agent on
Agent registered
connmanctl> scan wifi
connmanctl> services
*AO Wired                ethernet_b827eb8920a9_cable
*AR ¯\_(ツ)_/¯        wifi_801f024ae577_c2af5c5f28e38384295f2fc2af_managed_psk
    furb                 wifi_801f024ae577_66757262_managed_psk
    Unitymedia WifiSpot  wifi_801f024ae577_556e6974796d65646961205769666953706f74_managed_ieee8021x
    :o)                  wifi_801f024ae577_3a6f29_managed_psk
    ʕ•ᴥ•ʔ        wifi_801f024ae577_ca95e280a2e1b4a5e280a2ca94_managed_psk
    DIRECT-eE-Sonja's Fire TV wifi_801f024ae577_4449524543542d65452d536f6e6a6127732046697265205456_managed_psk
    DIRECT-B9-HP ENVY 4520 series wifi_801f024ae577_4449524543542d42392d485020454e5659203435323020736572696573_managed_psk
    SoHigh-WG            wifi_801f024ae577_536f486967682d5747_managed_psk
    o2-WLAN42            wifi_801f024ae577_6f322d574c414e3432_managed_psk
                         wifi_801f024ae577_hidden_managed_psk
    UPC1989729           wifi_801f024ae577_55504331393839373239_managed_psk
    wildline             wifi_801f024ae577_77696c646c696e65_managed_psk
    Internet             wifi_801f024ae577_496e7465726e6574_managed_psk
    UPC317EB59           wifi_801f024ae577_55504333313745423539_managed_psk
    HP-Print-BE-Officejet Pro 8610 wifi_801f024ae577_48502d5072696e742d42452d4f66666963656a65742050726f2038363130_managed_none
    UPC1BD68AB           wifi_801f024ae577_55504331424436384142_managed_psk
Scan completed for wifi
connmanctl> connect wifi_801f024ae577_556e6974796d65646961205769666953706f74_managed_ieee8021x
Error /net/connman/service/wifi_801f024ae577_556e6974796d65646961205769666953706f74_managed_ieee8021x: Invalid arguments
```

Connections via this wpa_supplicant.conf works:

```
network={ ssid=”Unitymedia WifiSpot” key_mgmt=WPA-EAP eap=PEAP identity=”unitymedia/myUsername” password=”myPassword” }
```

Hope someone have an idea what i´m doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried the instructions from Intel [connman page](https://web.archive.org/web/20141213065729/https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2014/12/04/connecting-intelr-edison-to-an-ieee-8021x-enterprise-hotspot-via-connman)? (Since this page got deleted, i had to get an old version from the Wayback Machine)

```
cat > /var/lib/connman/<pick_a_name>.config <<EOF
[global]
Name = <SSID>
Description = <fill in something descriptive>

[service_peap]
Type = wifi
Name = <SSID - like above>
EAP = peap
Phase2 = MSCHAPV2
Identity = <login>
Passphrase = <password>
EOF
```

After that, it is just a matter of running `connmanctl connect <IEEE802.1x service>` whereas the service name can be found by calling:

```
connmanctl enable wifi
connmanctl scan wifi
connmanctl services
```

Quoting the Intel page again, If it doesn't work on the first attempt try again. (It just took me 2 attempts to successfully log onto an IEEE 802.1x hotspot with Edison).

Comment: many thanks! 
I changed the config like you mentioned in your answer and no it works!

Comment: Works like a charm! To supplement this answer: more details about how to write the `<pick_a_name>.config` files in `/var/lib/connman` can be found on the man page of `service-name.config(5)` (type `man service-name.config.5` in a terminal).
Also, as a reminder, the SSID is just the name of the wifi network one wants to connect to ;).

Comment: There is a way to save hashed passphrase?